# the difference between web app and web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, web-applications, model, model-associations

Suppose you want to build a web service/app to manage a PMS (property management system). It contains two resources: room, and guest. You can
* add/remove/edit a room
* add/remove/edit a guest
* assign a guest to a room
1) Can you design and implement it in Ruby on Rails, as a web app?
2) Can you design and implement it in Ruby on Rails as web services? And please describe how you plan to use rspec to test it.

I do not know the difference between web app and web service. Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111243/web-service-vs-web-application -or- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615136/difference-between-web-services-and-web-application

Answer (score -1):

This is for web app mobile app native app and addmin panel  communicate database  service 
web usually used for remote(this is your central database) ,suppose that you have server and you are hosting web services file 1-> you have need create web services methods (insert update delete query) 2->via server URL with web services methods you can call 3->you can get or post method